# Excel VBA - Is it possible to call sub on error?

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I've been searching, but I can't really find something that answers this question.

I'm getting an error and I know whats causing it and it not really a problem. It just needs to run another sub before running the next line of code if this error occurs. So that made me wonder:

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
On Error Call Sheet1.TestSub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The best you can do is to branch to a separate section of code to handle the error and then branch back to the line immediately below the line raising the error. *(if you know what that line is!)*

Comment: I know the line, so if I make an error handler, call the sub in there and then branch back( `GoTo 0` ) is the best way to do this?

Comment: That is the only easy way....you need a **label** on the line below the "raiser".  Then **GOTO* that label.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much! will accept answer as soon as 10 minutes are over ;)

Comment: **Update your post if you need more help.**

Answer (score 9):

You could try something like this:

```
Sub test()
On Error GoTo 10
Set a = b
MsgBox ("still going")

Exit Sub
10:  test2
Resume Next

End Sub

Sub test2()
MsgBox ("Error")

End Sub
```